# ¿conflicto de rutas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

estoy realizando una petición ajax:
Peticion Ajax.

```
    function ver_detalles_team() {
  $(".card").hover(function () {
    let team_id = parseInt($(this).find("span:first-child").html());
    var carta = this;
    console.log("entro al evento hover")
    setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "team/" + team_id,
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 2000,
        error: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        },
        success: function (res) {
          $(carta).append(res);
        }

      })
    }, 4000)

  })
}
```

y la ruta configurada para que mi controlador pueda procesarla:

```
post 'team/:team_id',to:"teams#detalle_team"
```

cuando se ejecuta el evento "hover" , manda la peticion ajax , pero con la url cambiada a lo que le estoy mandando,ya que me sale un error en la consola de rails:[image: error]

a que se debe.Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AL utilizar `url: "team/"` estás estableciendo una ruta *relativa*, es decir, a tu ruta actual se le va a agregar `team/:id`; lo que buscas es una ruta *absoluta*, lo cual puedes lograr agregando `/` al inicio, así:

```
url: "/team/" + team_id,
```

Comment: gracias eso era , aun me falta por aprender.